# How to intercept mapbox-gl-js HTTP responses?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

We have a tileserver that can respond with 429 status code if the user has consumed all its quotas.

In my client app, I'd like to show a modal saying to the user it has consumed all its quotas. How can I intercept http responses from tileserver and check status code for requests issued by mapbox-gl-js ?

I tried with the **error** map event, but there are no information on status code.

Thanks,
Nicolas